# Not able to Run Python script Program Error: /usr/bin/python3^M: bad interpreter:

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, python3

So basically I am trying to run a multiclipboard program in python on ubuntu 20.04lts . I completed all the necessary requirements as per instructions but still got stuck .

```
#! /usr/bin/python3


import sys, pyperclip,shelve

mcbShelf=shelve.open('mcb')
if len(sys.argv)==3 and sys.argv[1].lower=='save':
    mcbShelf[sys.argv[2]]=pyperclip.paste()
elif len(sys.argv)==2:
    if sys.argv[1].lower()=='list':
        pyperclip.copy(str(list(mcbShelf.keys())))
    elif sys.argv[1] in mcbShelf:
        pyperclip.copy(str(mcbShelf[sys.argv[1]]))
mcbShelf.close()
```

I went to the correct directory and executed these commands.

```
 chmod +x  mcb.py
```

and for running the program ,

```
./mcb.py
```

Here I faced an Error as ,

```
bash: ./mcb.py: /usr/bin/python3^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Can you please help me out with it ? Am I missing out on anything or getting wrong somewhere ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bad carriage return character at the end of the first line in your code as told by the following error message.

```
bash: ./mcb.py: /usr/bin/python3^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

The `^M` is a carriage return character.  If you see this, you're probably looking at a file that originated in the DOS/Windows world, where an end-of-line is marked by a carriage return/newline pair, whereas in the Unix world, end-of-line is marked by a single newline. <sup>[source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32003/)</sup>

To get rid of the error make a new mcb.py file. Open the default Text Editor app, copy the code from your question and paste it into Text Editor (gedit in Ubuntu 20.04), save the code as mcb.sh, and run the code again with the following commands:

```
chmod +x  mcb.sh
./mcb.sh
```

Comment: dos2unix may help